# Pandas groupby add value of one line in group to all lines of the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Given a DataFrame `df` that looks roughly like this:

```
    TripID  time  Latitude  SectorID  sector_leave_time
 0      42     7      52.5         5                  8
 1      42     8      52.6         5                  8
 2      42     9      52.7         6                 10
 3      42    10      52.8         6                 10
 4       5     9      50.1         2                 10
 5       5    10      50.0         2                 10
 6       5    11      49.9         1                 12
 7       5    12      49.8         1                 12
```

I already computed the time at which a trip leaves a sector by getting the maximum timestamp within the sector. Now, I would like to add another column for the latitude at the point of sector_leave_time for each trip and sector, so the DataFrame becomes this:

```
    TripID  time  Latitude  SectorID  sector_leave_time  sector_leave_lat
 0      42     7      52.5         5                  8              52.6
 1      42     8      52.6         5                  8              52.6
 2      42     9      52.7         6                 10              52.8
 3      42    10      52.8         6                 10              52.8
 4       5     9      50.1         2                 10              50.0
 5       5    10      50.0         2                 10              50.0
 6       5    11      49.9         1                 12              49.8
 7       5    12      49.8         1                 12              49.8
```

So far I've only been able to add the `sector_leave_lat` to the line where `time == sector_leave_time`, i.e. when the trip leaves the sector, using the following line of code:

```
 df['sector_leave_lat'] = df.groupby('TripID').apply(lambda x : x.loc[x['time'] == x['sector_leave_time'], 'Latitude']).reset_index().set_index('level_1')['Latitude']
```

I know this line looks awful and I would like to add `sector_leave_lat` to all entries of that trip within that sector. I'm kind of running out of ideas, so I hope someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each trip-sector combination you want the last Latitude, sorted by time.

```
df['sector_leave_lat'] = df.sort_values('time').groupby(
    ['TripID', 'SectorID']
).transform('last')['Latitude']

outputs:
   TripID  time  Latitude  SectorID  sector_leave_time  test
0      42     7      52.5         5                  8  52.6
1      42     8      52.6         5                  8  52.6
2      42     9      52.7         6                 10  52.8
3      42    10      52.8         6                 10  52.8
4       5     9      50.1         2                 10  50.0
5       5    10      50.0         2                 10  50.0
6       5    11      49.9         1                 12  49.8
7       5    12      49.8         1                 12  49.8
```

As the sample data already appears sorted by time within each trip-sector group, the sorting here may be redundant

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that complicated if you are familiar with SQL :) 
The following code should do the trick :

```
#Given your dataframe :
df

   TripID  time  Latitude  SectorID  sector_leave_time
0    42.0   7.0      52.5       5.0                8.0
1    42.0   8.0      52.6       5.0                8.0
2    42.0   9.0      52.7       6.0               10.0
3    42.0  10.0      52.8       6.0               10.0
4     5.0   9.0      50.1       2.0               10.0
5     5.0  10.0      50.0       2.0               10.0
6     5.0  11.0      49.9       1.0               12.0
7     5.0  12.0      49.8       1.0               12.0

# Get the Latitude corresponding to time = sector_leave_time
df_max_lat = df.loc[df_merged.time==df.sector_leave_time, ['TripID', 'Latitude', 'SectorID']]
# Then you have :

   TripID  Latitude  SectorID
1    42.0      52.6       5.0
3    42.0      52.8       6.0
5     5.0      50.0       2.0
7     5.0      49.8       1.0

# Add the max latitude to original dataframe applying a left join
pd.merge(df, df_max_lat, on=['TripID', 'SectorID'], how='left', suffixes=('','_sector_leave'))
# You're getting :
    TripID  time    Latitude    SectorID    sector_leave_time   Latitude_sector_leave
0   42.0    7.0     52.5    5.0     8.0     52.6
1   42.0    8.0     52.6    5.0     8.0     52.6
2   42.0    9.0     52.7    6.0     10.0    52.8
3   42.0    10.0    52.8    6.0     10.0    52.8
4   5.0     9.0     50.1    2.0     10.0    50.0
5   5.0     10.0    50.0    2.0     10.0    50.0
6   5.0     11.0    49.9    1.0     12.0    49.8
7   5.0     12.0    49.8    1.0     12.0    49.8
```

There you go :)